# html quickform usage tips and tricks

Tags: php, html, pear

I am using html quickforms. I want to do have 2 forms like

```
<form1>
</form>

<form2>
</form>
```

2 forms in single page. how do i do this in a page using quickforms.

i use code like this to create form.

```
$form1 =& new HTML_QuickForm('form_filter', 'POST', '', '', array('class' => 'PSDDForm1'));
```

can i use a single renderer to print both forms ?

Comment: You don't mean `<form1></form1>` do you? You mean `<form name='name1'></form>`?

Comment: i mean to say <form name='name1'></form>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, use HTML_QuickForm2. Version 1 is deprecated.

To answer your question: just make sure that they have different names/ids, and it will work without problems.
Yes, you can use the same renderer to render multiple forms.